# Cassandra CQL paging for Composite key

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

Is there is any easy way to query wide row by paging. My schema is,

```
CREATE TABLE USER_LIKED_ITEMS (
user_id text,
event_id text,
item_id text,
description text,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, event_id, item_id)
);
```

I want to get all the rows for the given user_id (consider there are **500000 rows for a given user_id** with various combination of event_id and item_id) through paging with a count 25. The query I have tried is `select * from USER_LIKED_ITEMS where user_id = '101' LIMIT 25;` Once results is arrived then 25th record has a value

```
user_id = 101,
event_id = 25,
item_id = 25,
description = XXXXX
```

My next query is, `select * from USER_LIKED_ITEMS where user_id = '101' and event_id = '25' and item_id > '25' LIMIT 25;` Retrieves the results of 10 records having the last record value like,

```
user_id = 101,
event_id = 25,
item_id = 35,
description = XXXXX
```

So again I need to frame `select * from USER_LIKED_ITEMS where user_id = '101' and event_id > '25'`. So It is quite tricky and difficult to retrieve all the results by framing different query to retrieve all the results. Is there is any easy way to get all the record for the given user_id with pagination count of 25? I am using cassandra-1.2.15 and cassandra-driver-core-1.0.3.jar. Cassandra2.0 has paging support, but I am not allowed to upgrade cassandra version.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in 1.2 to ["page" through your results with the `token()` function and based on your partitioning key](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html) (which for you is `user_id`).  But I suspect if there was any value (to you) to query your results by just `user_id`, you would be doing it.

One solution that might be of some benefit to you, is to duplicate your data into a query table to solve this:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_LIKED_ITEMS_BY_PAGENO (
user_id text,
event_id text,
item_id text,
description text,
pageno bigint,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, pageno, event_id, item_id)
);
```

Of course this is assuming that you know at insert-time which rows belong on which page *(maybe for every 25 inserted, you increment* `pageno`*, or something similar)*.  But if you did, you could put them into a table like that, and then `SELECT` from it like this:

```
select * from USER_LIKED_ITEMS_BY_PAGENO 
where user_id = '101' and pageno = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I chose `event_id as clustering key` because I need to sort based on the event_id. At any time I will `query only for a corresponding user_id`. So token will not help for me. No other possibilities?

Comment: @JayaAnanthram Actually, all keys after the partitioning key are considered to be clustering keys.  So in theory (I haven't tested it) querying by `user_id` and `pageno` *should* still order your result set by `event_id`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But during the insertion time I will not knowing which page it will belongs to. So I need to frame separate query to find its page and again I need to insert. But there is also change to delete some of the data that belongs to different page. So it will give me trouble. Whether my schema will give any trouble in the future? For a given user_id there will be having around 100 million record. And I will query mostly descending order of event_id for a given user_id. Will this lead to any trouble? I decided to manually query like I have given in the question.

Comment: No, I don't think that design will lead to any future trouble (unless your business requirements change).  The only thing I'd keep in mind, is that Cassandra wide rows can support up to 2 billion columns, so as long as a single `user_id` doesn't exceed that, you should be ok.

Comment: Yes.. I am sure about it. It will not exceed beyond the limitations. But I am afraid about the issue given in [this link](http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/142key2pkz/performance-problem-with-large-wide-row-inserts-using-cql)

Comment: Good point, but that problem should not be an issue (long term)... Assuming of course that some day you are allowed to perform an upgrade to 2.1.x.