# Cassandra cql select query throws read time out exception always

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver, cqlsh

When I am trying to execute the below query, I am always getting QueryTimeOutException,

```
Exception is,
    com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)

Query is,
    SELECT * FROM my_test.my_table WHERE key_1 = 101 ORDER BY key_2 ASC LIMIT 25;
```

I am using cassandra version 2.1.0 with 3 nodes, Single DC with replication of 3, cassandra.yaml has all default values and I am having following keyspace and table as schema,

```
CREATE KEYSPACE my_test
  WITH REPLICATION = { 
    'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 
    'replication_factor' : 3
};

CREATE TABLE my_test.my_table (
    key_1 bigint,
    key_2 bigint,
    key_3 text,
    key_4 text,
    key_5 text,
    key_6 text,
    key_7 text,
    key_8 text,
    key_9 text,
    key_10 text,
    key_11 timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (key_1, key_2)
);
```

Currently the table has around 39000 records but initially it has 50000 records, 11000 records has been deleted for some business logic.

One of the solution **`to avoid such exception is to increase query read time out`**, But my schema and query are **`more direct why should I increase my read time out`**?
Since In my query I have given the partition key (key_1) so it should reach the destination exactly, after that I had specified the start range of parition key,
So it should retrieve with a maximum time of 2seconds, but is not so. But the below query is working fine and retrieved the results less than 1 seconds (`Difference is, ASC is not working and DESC is working`)

```
SELECT * FROM my_test.my_table WHERE key_1 = 101 ORDER BY key_2 DESC LIMIT 25;
```

Again as per schema the cluster key default order is ASC, So retrieving the data in ASC should be faster than DESC order as per cassandra documentation. 
But it is reverse in my case.

---

Again some clues, The following are the queries that has been tried through CQLSH.

The following query is working and retrieved the results less than 1 seconds

```
SELECT * FROM my_test.my_table WHERE key_1 = 101 AND key_2 > 1 AND key_2 < 132645 LIMIT 1;
```

But, the following query is not working and throws time out exception,

```
SELECT * FROM my_test.my_table WHERE key_1 = 101 AND key_2 > 1 AND key_2 < 132646 LIMIT 1;
```

But, the following queries are working, and retrieved results less than 1 seconds

```
SELECT * FROM my_test.my_table WHERE key_1 = 101 AND key_2 = 132644;
SELECT * FROM my_test.my_table WHERE key_1 = 101 AND key_2 = 132645;
SELECT * FROM my_test.my_table WHERE key_1 = 101 AND key_2 = 132646;
SELECT * FROM my_test.my_table WHERE key_1 = 101 AND key_2 = 132647;
```

Strange behaviour any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try turning on CQLSH tracing and see what it is telling you:  https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html

Comment: cqlsh> SELECT * FROM my_test.my_table WHERE key_1 = 101 ORDER BY key_2 ASC LIMIT 500;
code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'data_retrieved': False, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 1}
Statement trace did not complete within 10 seconds

Comment: @bechbd I guess query trace will give result if the query succeeds.

Comment: likely unrelated, but avoid using a .0 release from before the new tick tock model. 2.1.0 is the least stable of the 2.1s, upgrading to 2.1.13 would be a huge improvement (lots of bug fixes).

Comment: How many `key_2`s are under each `key_1`?  You're querying for a `key_2` range of 1 to 132646...  Are there really 132646 of them?

Comment: @Chris Lohfink Thanks for the suggestion. Surely will try to upgrade the version. But I need to know the root cause of the issue since it is occurring in production box.

Comment: @Aaron For each key_1 there will be around 1000000 key_2. So the range will be starts from 1, but some of the range like 10 to 20 will not be there again 21 to 30 will be present and so on... 132646 value is available in key_2

Comment: BTW- +1'd and favorited.  From an academic perspective, this question is pure gold.  I don't remember anyone else doing something like this, and this is a *great* example to link in the future.  Albeit, it's an example of what *not* to do, but those are equally (if not more) important to have around.

Comment: @Aaron Yes I agree with you. I am aware of performance impacts of too wide row. When I design the schema I have raised a question  regarding too wide row performance degrade over a year ago [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138526/cassandra-cql-paging-for-composite-key#answer-28151045) (refer last but one comment ) and it was answered by you and your answer was "cassandra upgrade will fix it".

Comment: @Aaron Though the reason for choosing the wide row schema is, my business requirement is pure data page concept which has paginated view (page by page, last page, first page), count, search. For those, I cant able to design as you shown in your example. So we go in a way to have wide row. If the data touches too wide then we have a work around to put in separate partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved **`after restarting all the 3 cassandra servers`**. I don't know what the hell makes trouble.. Since it is in production server couldn't able to get exact Root Cause.

Answer (score 1):

> For each key_1 there will be around 1000000 key_2.

And this is what happens when you take the 2 billion cells per partition limit, and try to use all of it.  I know I've answered plenty of posts here before by acknowledging that there is a hard limit of 2 billion cells per partition, your (very) wide row will become ungainly and probably time-out *long* before that.  This is what I believe you are seeing.

The solution here, is a technique called "bucketing."  Basically, you have to find an additional key to partition your data by.  Too many CQL rows are being written to the same data partition, and bucketing would help bring the ratio of partition to clustering keys back to a sane level.

The logical way to go about bucketing, is with a time element.  I see your last key is a timestamp.  I don't know how many rows each `key_1` gets in a day, but let's say that you only get a few thousand every month.  In that case, I would create an additional partition key of `month_bucket`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_test.my_table (
    key_1 bigint,
    key_2 bigint,
    ...
    key_11 timestamp,
    month_bucket text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((key_1,month_bucket) key_2)
);
```

That would allow you to support a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_test.my_table 
WHERE key_1 = 101 AND month_bucket = '201603'
  AND key_2 > 1 AND key_2 < 132646 LIMIT 1;
```

Again, bucketing on month is just an example.  But basically, you need to find an additional column to partition your data on.

Comment: Yes of course I am aware of it but when this issue happens, the table has around 39000 records only but initially it has 50000 records, 11000 records has been deleted for some business logic. This was I mentioned in my question. So It has 50000 records with some tombstones row. So it should work as my expectations.

Comment: And also similarly, default cluster order is ASC so in my case ASC should work very fast than DESC (Reason: Very large wide row...) but it is reverse in mycase. This also I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram "So it should work as my expectations."  And yet, it does not.  Look, I know that nobody likes being told that they need to completely blow-away and reload their data for a model change *after* they've gone to production.  But your rows are just too wide, and there really isn't a quick fix for that.  Go ahead and test both models out with cassandra-stress, and not only should it work, but I bet your op/s will be way-higher with a "bucket" than with a very wide row.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I am aware of performance impacts of too wide row. When I design the schema I have raised a question regarding too wide row performance degrade over a year ago link (refer last but one comment ) and it was answered by you and your answer was "cassandra upgrade will fix it".

Comment: Though the reason for choosing the wide row schema is, my business requirement is pure data page concept which has paginated view (page by page, last page, first page), count, search. For those, I cant able to design as you shown in your example. So we go in a way to have wide row. If the data touches too wide then we have a work around to put in separate partition.

Comment: But my doubt is, still there are only 50000 row whether the performance impacts will be matters for such small set of records?